# Redirecting to the App Store from iFrame on iOS - Safari

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari, mobile-safari, velo

### In a Nutshell:

I have an iframe that includes javascript code to redirect the user to another URL. I am doing the following inside my iframe:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://abc.xyz";
```

I noticed that, on iOS Safari, this method works with any URL except app store URLs. For example, The following code does not work on Safari on iOS (but works on Chrome):

```
window.top.location.href = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id1125901708";
```

After deep investigation, it looks like Apple started **preventing iframe redirections to the app store**. Is my assumption correct? Is there any work around this? *Ultimately, I want to redirect the iOS Safari user to my app on the app store*.

---

### Further Explanation:

I have a Wix website, and in one of my pages I need to do redirection based on the user's device (e.g. if iOS then redirect to the app store, and if Android then redirect to Google play... etc.). It looks like the only way to include javascript code in Wix is by clicking (Add -> HTML Code) which will include an iframe in the page. Inside my iframe, I have the following javascript code:

```
<script>
    var url;
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

    // Windows Phone must come first because its UA also contains "Android"
    if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
        url = "http://www.sibly.co";
    } else if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sibly.sibly";
    } else if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        url = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id1125901708";
    } else {
        url = "http://www.sibly.co";
    }

    window.top.location.href = url;
</script>
```

I included this further explanation to explore on the following other possible solutions:

- Is there any other way to include javascript code on Wix without the
  use of iframe?
- Is there any other way to do redirection on Wix based
  on the user's device?